# How do you model the radial strain on a disc?

Tags: stress-strain, solid-mechanics

I have a polymer disc with uniform force distributed evenly around its circumference (*see below*). How can I model the strain in the disc as a function of distance from the center?

[image: Disc with uniform force]

As an extension, would it be possible to model this in an FEM program like Comsol? My goal is to make a MEMs device that can stretch a PDMS disc relatively uniformly. (I'm an electrical engineering graduate student with limited background in solid mechanics)